# how to update android application on wso2 emm 1.1.0 ?

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot

In wso2 1.1.0 (https://localhost:9443/publisher) there is a feature to add application. But I did't find any feature to update that application. Or when I upload same application with updated version . it shows me error that application is already there.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've figured out how update an already installed app is by going to the **App Management** tab, selecting your latest version of the app in question, and hitting the install button under the **Roles** tab (NOT the Users tab). It will send the install command to any devices listed under roles you have checked, even if they already have the app installed. Keep in mind this will install the app on *all* the devices, even devices that already have the version you're trying to put out.

Note: there is a patch found on [EMM-686](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/EMM-686) that must be implemented in order to upload multiple versions of the same app to the Publisher. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32370213/wso2-emm-app-management-version-bug/33296670#33296670) for instructions on how to implement it.